# Passing an object as a parameter in a constructor

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass an object into a constructor as a parameter. Is the following code allowed? Particularly the portion where I pass `Toyota` and `Corolla` into `Car car`, and then into `String brand` and `String model`.

```
public class Car {
    private String brand, model;

    public Car(String brand, String model) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
    }

    // getters and setters
}

public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private Car car;

    public Customer(String name, Car car) {
        this.name = name;
        this.car = car;
    }

    // getters and setters
}

public class Service {
    Customer customer = new Customer("John", "Toyota", "Corolla");
}
```

Comment: What is your problem / question?

Comment: You can only have 1 public class in file, which should be named same way as your java file (capitalized of course).

Comment: You should read the error that you get when you compile this and provide it as part of your question.

Comment: In the future, please ask a much more complete question. This one is missing key information -- such as an actual and specific question. Please go through the [ask]. -

Comment: "Is the following code allowed?" what did your compiler tell you when you tried to compile it? If you haven't tried to compile it, then you need to delete this question and do the required research by compiling it yourself first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Customer doesn't have a constructor that takes 3 Strings, so you have to pass a String and a Car object in:

Change

```
Customer customer = new Customer("John", "Toyota", "Corolla");
```

to

```
Customer customer = new Customer("John", new Car("Toyota", "Corolla"));
```

Solution 2 is to give Customer a 3 String constructor and create a Car object in the constructor.

```
public Customer(String name, Car car) {
    this.name = name;
    this.car = car;
}

// and
public Customer(String name, String brand, String model) {
    this.name = name;
    this.car = new Car(brand, model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Service` class to:-

```
public class Service {
    Customer customer = new Customer("John", new Car("Toyota", "Corolla")); 
}
```